# BeagleBone Slackware UART issue

Tags: slackware, beagleboneblack, uart

I'm working with a custom made image of **Slackware ARM 14.1** with kernel **3.8.X** since about 3 years and now needed to upgrade kernel for cdc-acm driver and watchdog.

I've tried different kernels from distro supplied with BeagleBone (**Debian 7.11** to **9.5**, kernel **4.1.X** to **4.14.X**). Each time I replace files in /boot/ and /lib/modules and /lib/firmware, they are all booting properly but never been able to make UART working again.

With kernel **3.8.X**, I was using /boot/uEnv.txt line :

```
optargs=capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART1,BB-UART2,BB-UART4
```

I know there was changes between 4.1.X and 4.4.X and 4.14.X but tried each configurations with no success. Is it possible the issue is because I have a FAT partition for /boot/ and EXT4 partition for / ? Because I'll have to remote update systems so will not be able to change partitions.

Also could it be possible that the issue is the U-Boot version? From the debug serial :

```
U-Boot 2014.04-rc2-00015-g99288ca (Mar 12 2014 - 09:49:41)
```

EDIT :

Updated the U-Boot, still the same issue

```
U-Boot 2018.09-00002-g0b54a51eee (Sep 10 2018 - 19:41:39 -0500), Build: jenkins-github_Bootloader-Builder-65
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used the kernel 4.4.54 from image bone-debian-9.5-iot-armhf-2018-10-07-4gb.img which serial ports work as ttyS? instead of ttyO?.

Something probably wrong with 4.14.X configuration (uEnv.txt or other), but I'm satisfied with 4.4.X for now.